# predict next career suggestion

Tags: nlp, recommender-system, word2vec, gensim, gpt

I have a dataset having job and description. i want to make model which can predict what are the thing that user needs to improve when the user inputs his skills.

For an example,

If he has skills - Python, Data Visualization, and etc
The model should predict - DataScience, Machine Learning etc..

Note : The dataset contains the job description which contains various skills a candidate needs to have. model needs to predict from those data,

fine tune the dataset on GPT model is not recommended.

If you have any idea how to approach to this problem, I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something an apriori algorithm could deal with (https://towardsdatascience.com/apriori-association-rule-mining-explanation-and-python-implementation-290b42afdfc6)

The apriori algorithm typically deals with "shopping cart" problems. If you've purchased these 4 items, what is the most likely 5th.

Based on how you describe the problem, this might be a good approach to pursue.